# Is this a bug with LEAD() IGNORE NULLS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, lead, sql-server-2022

I was testing and comparing various forms of the `LAST()`, `LEAD()`, `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` window functions and appear to have found a bug with `LEAD() IGNORE NULLS`.

Instead of the expected results, it seems to return the same values as `LAG() IGNORE NULLS`. I would expect it to return the same as `FIRST_VALUE(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)`

Am I correct to consider this a bug, or am I missing something? If a bug, what is the best place to report it?

```
-- With nulls
CREATE TABLE T (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Value INT)
INSERT T
VALUES
    (NULL), (11), (22), (33),
    (NULL), (44), (55), (66),
    (NULL), (77), (88), (99),
    (NULL)

SELECT *
    , LAG(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS Lag
    , LAG(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS LagI
    , LEAD(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS Lead
    , LEAD(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS [LeadI ???]
    , FIRST_VALUE(Value) IGNORE NULLS
          OVER(
              ORDER BY Id
              ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING -- Strictly following
          )
          AS [FirstISF (= expected LeadI)]
FROM T
ORDER BY T.Id
```

Results:

| Id | Value | Lag | LagI | Lead | LeadI ??? | FirstISF (= expected LeadI) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | 11 | *null* | 11 |
| 2 | 11 | *null* | *null* | 22 | *null* | 22 |
| 3 | 22 | 11 | 11 | 33 | 11 | 33 |
| 4 | 33 | 22 | 22 | *null* | 22 | 44 |
| 5 | *null* | 33 | 33 | 44 | 33 | 44 |
| 6 | 44 | *null* | 33 | 55 | 33 | 55 |
| 7 | 55 | 44 | 44 | 66 | 44 | 66 |
| 8 | 66 | 55 | 55 | *null* | 55 | 77 |
| 9 | *null* | 66 | 66 | 77 | 66 | 77 |
| 10 | 77 | *null* | 66 | 88 | 66 | 88 |
| 11 | 88 | 77 | 77 | 99 | 77 | 99 |
| 12 | 99 | 88 | 88 | *null* | 88 | *null* |
| 13 | *null* | 99 | 99 | *null* | 99 | *null* |

The above query (and a few others) are available in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jG17e0vv).

Comment: No repro on 16.0.4080.1 - DB Fiddle is 16.0.1000.6

Comment: maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate4#2278800

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: DB Fiddle is using RTM version with no CUs applied (bug fixes) - the issue was probably fixed in CU 4

Comment: Case closed I guess.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Just so I am clear, is 16.0.4080.1 Cumulative Update 4 and you have confirmed that the bug is no longer reproduceable on that version?

Comment: 16.0.4080.1 is CU 8 and on that `@@version` the `LeadI ???` and `FirstISF (= expected LeadI)` columns have the same values so the fix could be in any CU <= 8. I found it documented in CU4

Comment: Step 1 of "is something a bug", @TN , is make sure you are using the latest version of the software. Many bugs are fixed in later updates.

Comment: @ThomA - *Background: This all started when I asked myself `LAST_VALUE()` and `LAG()`, `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LEAD()` and started experimenting.  DB<>fiddle was just the handy test platform, since I don't have 2022 readily available locally.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug - but looks like it has now been fixed (presumably [2278800 in CU4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate4#2278800). The `@@VERSION` reported by DB Fiddle is `16.0.4080.1` - which is the RTM version of SQL Server 2022 with no bugfixes.

On [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YxudZFHP) for the following query...

```
SELECT  LAG(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS LagI,
        LEAD(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS [LeadI ???]
FROM T
ORDER BY T.Id
```

The execution plan is

```
 |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([WindowCount1009]) DEFINE:([Expr1003]=LAST_VALUE_IGNORE_NULLS([dbo].[T].[Value]), [Expr1004]=LAST_VALUE_IGNORE_NULLS([dbo].[T].[Value]), [dbo].[T].[Id]=ANY([dbo].[T].[Id])))
       |--Window Spool(ROWS BETWEEN:(UNBOUNDED, [BottomRowNumber1006]))
            |--Segment
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([BottomRowNumber1006]=[RowNumber1005]-(1)))
                      |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([RowNumber1005]=row_number))
                           |--Segment
                                |--Sort(ORDER BY:([dbo].[T].[Id] ASC))
                                     |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[T]))
```

It only has one sort (`Id Ascending`) and one window spool etc.

In CU 8 (returns correct results) the execution plan calculates both window functions separately (with both an ascending and a descending sort) and the plan has twice as many operators.

---

```
  |--Sort(ORDER BY:([dbo].[T].[Id] ASC))
       |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([WindowCount1022]) DEFINE:([Expr1004]=LAST_VALUE_IGNORE_NULLS([dbo].[T].[Value]), [dbo].[T].[Id]=ANY([dbo].[T].[Id]), [Expr1003]=ANY([Expr1003])))
            |--Window Spool(ROWS BETWEEN:(UNBOUNDED, [BottomRowNumber1016]))
                 |--Segment
                      |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([BottomRowNumber1016]=[RowNumber1015]-(1)))
                           |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([RowNumber1015]=row_number))
                                |--Segment
                                     |--Sort(ORDER BY:([dbo].[T].[Id] DESC))
                                          |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([WindowCount1019]) DEFINE:([Expr1003]=LAST_VALUE_IGNORE_NULLS([dbo].[T].[Value]), [dbo].[T].[Id]=ANY([dbo].[T].[Id]), [dbo].[T].[Value]=ANY([dbo].[T].[Value])))
                                               |--Window Spool(ROWS BETWEEN:(UNBOUNDED, [BottomRowNumber1014]))
                                                    |--Segment
                                                         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([BottomRowNumber1014]=[RowNumber1013]-(1)))
                                                              |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([RowNumber1013]=row_number))
                                                                   |--Segment
                                                                        |--Sort(ORDER BY:([dbo].[T].[Id] ASC))
                                                                             |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[T]))
```

The above execution plan does actually have three sorts. One `id asc`, then `id desc`, then `id asc` for the final `order by`.

This can be reduced to two by reversing the order of the columns in the `SELECT` list

```
SELECT  LEAD(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS [LeadI ???],
        LAG(Value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS LagI
FROM T
ORDER BY T.Id
```

Comment: Isn't the last part a bug as well? Or why would order of columns matter?

Comment: @siggemannen - order of columns **shouldn't** matter but SQL Server only spends a limited amount of effort on avoiding extra sorts here so it does. Itzik Ben Gan looks at that here https://sqlperformance.com/2022/05/t-sql-queries/are-you-sorted-window-ordering

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for a very informative answer!